# Can I put an entity more than one times on a ER diagram?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I'm making an ER diagram where there's an admin entity which is in relation with all the other entities. Because of these relations the diagram is kinda cluttered, can I put this same entity on the diagram more than one time to make it more readable?

Comment: You can do what's good for you if you're the only one needing to understand it. If one table is really noted everywhere it might be simpler to draw it to one side and NOT draw the relationships for that table?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.